# Запросы в redbeanphp

Tags: php, redbeanphp

Как в redbean написать несколько условий в select. Есть код:

```
$tv = R::getAll('SELECT * FROM `offers` WHERE `categoryId` ='.R::genSlots($_GET['id_ct']).' AND `my_id` = '.$value->product_id.'');
```

в $_GET['id_ct'] лежат массив элементов.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isArray(R::genSlots($_GET['id_ct']))) {
  $cat = 'IN ('.implode(',',R::genSlots($_GET['id_ct'])).')';
} else {
  $cat = '='.R::genSlots($_GET['id_ct']);
}
$tv = R::getAll('SELECT * FROM `offers` WHERE `categoryId` '.$cat.' AND `my_id` = '.$value->product_id.'');
```

Немного объяснений:
https://oracleplsql.ru/in-mysql.html

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]